# How am I supposed to implement multiple select option in angular-material?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have checked the docs and the demos, but alas!! I have not found any reference of implementing the multiple select option like select 2 using angular-material.
Could anyone please tell me how to make it work?

Comment: Adding to the question a bit: 
As of 0.8.3, the docs do not provide a demo of 'multiple'. Using the multiple attribute as a boolean option fails: it seems to be presence based (which is pure evil, I must add).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Splaktar's answer is correct: Just add *multiple* to your *md-select*.

Codepen for working solution: http://codepen.io/ansgar-john/pen/RWPVEO?editors=101

HTML

```
<div>
  <md-input-container>
    <md-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.likedAnimals" placeholder="please select">
      <md-option ng-repeat="a in ctrl.animals" value="{{a}}">{{a}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp')
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
        this.likedAnimals = ["mouse", "dog"];
        this.animals = ["mouse", "dog", "cat", "bird"];
  });
})();
```

Code based on Stack Overflow answer: [How am I supposed to implement multiple select option in angular-material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655946/how-am-i-suppose-to-implement-multiple-select-option-in-angular-material#28912020)

Comment: This works, But how is posible stack the selected items one on top of the other and not inline like its on the example and remove the comas?

Comment: Id it possible to add image in the select options?

Comment: is there possible to add select all in combobox??

Answer (score 7):

You can look at the docs for the directive [here](https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.select/directive/mdSelect).

**Attributes**

multiple (optional): boolean - Whether it's multiple.

```
<md-select ng-model="someModel" placeholder="Select a state" multiple="true">
    <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in neighborhoods2">{{ opt }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

If this doesn't work, I've heard that `md-multiple` might work but that the docs just aren't updated yet. I haven't been able to verify this yet though.

Comment: this is not Working :-(

Comment: I believe that multiple selection has been disabled. I think that they want people to use Chips for multiple select. The story here is still evolving.

Comment: I hope not, chips is ugly as heck and doesn't fit into the normal look and feel of a form with other selection controls.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.chips)

You can apply your own custom template as well.

Comment: Anyone who is looking for multi-select with add option, thats the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to allow me to use an ng-repeat along with some md-select that were multi, and some that weren't (as of Angular 1.4.7):

#### index.html

```
<md-input-container ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <label>{{item.title}}</label>
            <div ng-include="item.multiselect == 'true' ? 'm_selectfragment.html' : 's_selectfragment.html'"></div>
   </md-input-container>
```

#### Javascript

```
$scope.items = 
        [{title: 'funny',
        selected: '', 
        names: [
            {name: 'some name'}, 
            {name: 'other name'},
            {name: 'more?'}, 
            {name: 'say wha???'}             
            ],
         multiselect: "false"   
        }, 
        {title: 'serious', 
        selected: '', 
        names: [
           {name: 'Obama'},
        {name: 'Trump'},
        {name: 'Hillary'},
        {name: 'Putin'}               
            ],
         multiselect: "true"   
        }];
```

#### m_selectfragment.html

```
<md-select name="item.title" ng-model="item.selected" multiple="true">
<md-option ng-repeat="name in item.names" value="{{name.name}}">{{name.name}}
</md-option>
```

#### s_selectfragment.html

```
<md-select name="item.title" ng-model="item.selected">
<md-option ng-repeat="name in item.names" value="{{name.name}}">{{name.name}}
</md-option>
```